# Issues with connecting to remote windows machine using Jsch

Tags: java, jsch

I am currently working on making one Java application which will execute commands (from command prompt) of remotely located Windows machine.

For developing this I have tried following:

1. Used Jsch library, the application worked well when connected to **Unix machines**, I was able to get list of processes using 'prstat -a' command, but when I tried with **Windows machine**, it gave me **ConnectException**(Timed out)

   ```
   private final static String HOSTNAME = "SOMECOMPUTERNAME.XXX.XXX.XXX.COM";//
   private final static String USERNAME = "SOMEUSERNAME";
   private final static String PASSWORD = "SOMEPASSWORD";
   private final static int PORT = 22;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       JSch jscc = new JSch();
       try {
           Session session = jscc.getSession(USERNAME, HOSTNAME, PORT);
           session.setPassword(PASSWORD);
           Properties localProperties = new Properties();
           localProperties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
           session.setConfig(localProperties);

           session.connect(60000);
           System.out.println("Session connected");

       } catch (JSchException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

The target machine info:

- Windows x64 workstation
- Latest version of Java installed
- Doesn't use any encryption

Please guide into this, Can it be done with Jsch library, if not that which method you can recommend.

Following things you can assume:

- I don't want any code in target machine. So a Java application which resides in my workstation and just executes some simple window commands, like dir or start applicationName in the target window machine
- I have username and corresponding passwords
- I don't have the ipaddress, just a full computer name in format as shown in the code above(HOSTNAME)

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Regards,

icr

Comment: Hmm, does the target machine actually have an SSH server installed? Have you tried to connect to it using an SSH client?

Comment: I guess not, I do have to check with the support team though. What if it is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have SSH installed by default. You will need a SSH client for windows.

I prefer OpenSSH....its free and works perfectly